# Which is better practice in Unity? GetComponent<>() or making the variable public?

Tags: unity, performance

There are two main ways I am aware of to modify an attached component.
Say, the component attached to an object is  of type `Animator` and the name is `animator`.

So, in the script, I can write

```
private Animator animator;
```

and then call the function

```
animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
```

Or, I can define the variable as public

```
public Animator animator
```

and then, drag&drop in the Unity UI.
Which one is the better practice?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a third option I sometimes like to use:

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(Animator))]
public class MyScript : MonoBehaviour {

    [SerializeField, HideInInspector]
    private Animator _animator;
    
    void OnValidate() {
        _animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }
}
```

Breaking this down...

- `RequireComponent` ensures the object actually has the component I need, and Unity will add it at edit time if I forget it, or complain at me if I try to remove it.
- Using both `SerializeField` and `HideInInspector` ensures we can save a value to the variable at edit time and have it save with the scene / carry through into game, without cluttering the Inspector with something we don't need to set manually.
- `OnValidate()` gets called when we add or modify this component, only in the editor, so it can automatically wire up the reference for us without any search cost at runtime.

I wouldn't say this is "the best practice" — a public or serialized private variable is a lot more concise and does basically the same job, this just insulates you against forgetting to assign it. It's a little cheaper than finding the component on startup, but that cost isn't huge, so you can weigh whether the alternatives are worth the extra typing or hook-up. ;)

---

Another alternative you might like: [Alex Hetherington has created a handy editor script that simplifies linking up component references](https://twitter.com/FootnotesFuture/status/1473306357562552324). Now you can just add a `[Resolve]` attribute above the serialized component field you want to populate, and it will add a one-click button to populate the field (even populating an array of references), without you having to write your own initialization in `OnValidate()` or elsewhere. [Here's a link to the GitHub repository with this and other utilities you can add to your project](https://github.com/alexjhetherington/FootnoteUtilities).

Comment: I'm a little confused, how is using `[SerializeField, HideInInspector]` any different than just not having either (excluding custom editors more complex things like that)? If it's hidden how are you setting values to it in edit?

Comment: @Jake with this method, you don't manually assign the reference in the Inspector. The `OnValidate` method does it for you in code. That's why we hide it from the inspector. But in order for that reference that was assigned in code at edit time to be saved in the scene/prefab and survive into the built game, it needs to be serialized. Unity's serializer skips over private fields by default, so we need to tell it to save this one as an exception to the rule.

Comment: Do you mean serailzeField will save the variable on the disk but hide in inspector will hide it for simplification? Hide in inspector is also overriding seralize field behaviour?

Comment: You could answer that question by trying it. [SerializeField] does not hide the variable from the inspector, so to hide it we also add [HideInInspector]

Answer (score 2):

First of all when you type

```
public Animator animator
```

what you're talking about is a SerializedField. You can do the same with private variables by doing

```
[SerializeField] private Animator animator
```

But as for your question the second one is better because it is faster. Using one or two `GetComponent<>()` calls generally isn't too bad, but if you use many in a single frame it could be a problem.